# Aligning radio-buttons with labels in HTML

Tags: html, radio-button, radio-group

I have radio buttons for multiple choice selection. Labels of radio buttons can be consist of multiple lines (see examples below) (they can technically be mini web pages).

How can I produce a form that looks like second example (below) and select the radio button when its' label is clicked (without javascript) as implemented in first example below?

**First Example:**

```html
<div class="answers">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="336"/>
    <i><p>Morbi consequat at mi vitae hendrerit. </p>
       <p>Quisque pharetra, mauris id blandit <strong>consectetur</strong>.</p>
    </i>
</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="337"/>
    <i><p>Morbi consequat at mi vitae hendrerit. Quisque pharetra, mauris id
        blandit consectetur, erat risus mattis quam, ac venenatis felis ante nec
        mi. Curabitur diam lectus, ultrices a consequat sodales, laoreet eu
        odio. Quisque sit amet pulvinar ligula. Sed ullamcorper metus non odio
        sagittis malesuada. Fusce a lorem nisl. Fusce eu magna sed ante blandit
        semper. Vivamus pulvinar nulla nec elit pharetra vestibulum.</p>
    </i>
</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="338"/>
    <i><p><img alt="alt text"           src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/90/Wikipedia_article_count_graph_28_march_2003.png"
               title="Logo Title Text 1"></p>
    </i>
</label>
</div>
```

**Second Example:**

```html
<div class="answers">
  <table border="0">
    <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="336" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
      <i><p>Morbi consequat at mi vitae hendrerit. </p>
         <p>Quisque pharetra, mauris id blandit <strong>consectetur</strong>.</p>
      </i>
  </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="337" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
      <i><p>Morbi consequat at mi vitae hendrerit. Quisque pharetra, mauris id
          blandit consectetur, erat risus mattis quam, ac venenatis felis ante nec
          mi. Curabitur diam lectus, ultrices a consequat sodales, laoreet eu
          odio. Quisque sit amet pulvinar ligula. Sed ullamcorper metus non odio
          sagittis malesuada. Fusce a lorem nisl. Fusce eu magna sed ante blandit
          semper. Vivamus pulvinar nulla nec elit pharetra vestibulum.</p>
      </i>
  </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="338" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
      <i><p><img alt="alt text"           src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/90/Wikipedia_article_count_graph_28_march_2003.png"
                 title="Logo Title Text 1"></p>
      </i>
  </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

My best advice is to google this type of question first. I googled it myself and immediately found this example: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Comment: Can you explain how the link you sent applies to the problem stated above? A working example will be helpful.